# Will Brahmacharis (life long bachelors) get moksha?

Tags: moksha, sanyasi

It is said that we have to clear our debts towards parents and ancestors (***Pitru Runa***) by begetting children before we can attain moksha. But people who take Brahmacharya don't marry. Will these Brahmacharis get moksha?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about people who stay in the Brahmacharya Ashrama or are you also talking about people who go directly from Brahmacharya to becoming Sanyasis?

Comment: all Brahmacharyas in general and brahmacharyas who stay in ashramas in particular.

Comment: If you are talking about bachelorhood, it is said one needs to either renounce (take up sanyasa) or beget progeny to advance to higher states.

Comment: @RaviJ Good info.you can elaborately explain  this as answer.

Comment: [brahmacharya](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=brahmacarya&script=&direction=SE&link=yes) = state, brahmachari = person

Comment: @sv. i first used "Bramhacharis" but later changed to "Brahmacharyas". BTW, here is another good [Sanskrit Dictionary](http://www.andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php)

Comment: @The Destroyer - I don't know the answer from the scriptures, but Bheeshma who was a brahmachari, did get liberation, isn't it? So, my view is every body is eligible for moksha whether he/she is bachelor, spinster, grihasta, Sanyasi etc based on ParaBrahman's Will and Grace. BTW, for the departed souls, the son whose father has departed has to do tarpanam every amavasya and on special occasions also. How many son's are doing it? In that pitru runa will never be over come. I think, it is samanya dharma that one should have a son to overcome pitru runa. Moksha is visesha dharma, I suppose.

Comment: @The Destroyer - In the story dadhibanda getting moksha, even pot got moksha, so everyone is eligible for moksha by God's grace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following are excerpts from the authoritative text on Sri Ramana Maharshi's sayings - Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> Devotee.: Is not brahmacharya (celibacy) necessary for realisation of
>   the Self?
>
> Maharshee.: Brahmacharya is ‘living in Brahman’. It has no connection
>   with celibacy as commonly understood. A real brahmachari, that is one
>   who lives in Brahman, finds bliss in the Brahman which is the same as
>   the Self. Why then should you look for other sources of happiness? In
>   fact the emergence from the Self has been the cause of all the misery.
>
> D.: Celibacy is a sine qua non for Yoga?
>
> M.: So it is. Celibacy is certainly an aid to realisation among so
>   many other aids.
>
> D.: Is it then not indispensable? Can a married man realise the Self?
>
> M.: Certainly, it is a matter of fitness of mind. Married or
>   unmarried, a man can realise the Self, because that is here and now.
>   If it were not so, but attainable by some efforts at some other time,
>   and if it were new and something to be acquired, it would not be
>   worthy of pursuit. Because what is not natural cannot be permanent
>   either. But what I say is that the Self is here and now and alone.

Hope this will answer your question

Comment: so pitru runa doesn't have effect on brahmacharyas. right?

Comment: If PITRU RUNA means procreating children in order to continue the lineage, then the answer would be YES.