# Is a woman required to be chaste even before being married and during marriage?

Tags: marriage, women, sex

A widow is [required to be chaste after the death of her husband to attain heaven](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50350/23709).

1. Is a woman required to be chaste even before being married? Or can a woman have affairs with other men and then get married to some other man (it is common phenomena now-a-days). Do such women go to heaven?
2. Is she required to be chaste while being married? Can a woman who cheats on her husband or a woman who indulges in adultery with the consent of her husband go to heaven?

Comment: Leveve alone women. Men those who do adultery go to hell for sure. If priest does he losses right to perform Pooja to idol because sanctity of idol is lost the priest losses his caste according to manusmiriti

Comment: @PrasannaR Is it also adultery to have affairs before marriage ? Because it is common now-a-days . So, most people will to hell ?

Comment: According bannaje women have less punishment because they already suffering by different natural happenings as soon as one cycle is passed she is pure she should be treated according as pure but one gets pregnant and kill the unborn will be punished either in this birth or later birth

Comment: For men it's tantamount to cheating

Comment: @PrasannaR Then why are widows punished ? Because widows too should get purified.

Comment: Female mostly are not punished like men in hell because they cannot be instigator only thing here is their Chitta becomes corrupted lead to numerous birth to reach current state it's snake and ladder game

Comment: for your reference read pingala story of srimad bhagavatam she was born as trivakra got the grace of service krishna wiht sandalwood paste. I would suggest Female offer sandol wood paste to krishna to obsolve from anysin of the past and get elevated. The offering should be of true love to krishna. Krishna is so much of karunya in his entire avatar to women only. Either Rishi patni who offerred ghee and butter offering meant for yagnya of their husbands and gopika stree and many more..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification regarding adultery, extra-marital relations](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/clarification-regarding-adultery-extra-marital-relations)

Comment: @PrasannaR I couldn't understand the snake and ladder game reference which you gave. Could you explain it more clearly. 
Also some women rape minor children (in these cases child is not the instigator), do they not get punished in hell even for this ?

Comment: @river read swami vishwananda answer which He quotes from BG that is what I ment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manu Smriti says that the religious ceremony of marriage is never meant for ladies who have lost their virginity:

> 8.226. The nuptial texts are applied solely to virgins, (and) nowhere among men to females who have lost their virginity, for such (females)
> are excluded from religious ceremonies.

If the father knowingly does Kanyadana of such a daughter who has already lost her virginity then that father is eligible for a punishment. But not so when he declares that blemish beforehand.

> 8.205. He who gives (a damsel in marriage), having first openly declared her blemishes, whether she be insane, or afflicted with
> leprosy, or have lost her virginity, is not liable to punishment.

So, yes women are required to be chaste before marriage.